# Cloudera CDH 4.6.0 - Hive metastore service not starting

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh

I installed `Cloudera CDH 4.6.0` on my `Centos 6.2` linux server machine (Cloudera manager - 4.8). I am able to start few services, however not able to start the Hive metastore service.

Cloudera is using Postgre SQL as the remote metatore DB. My host name is `delvmpll2`, but when starting Hive service, it is giving `java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost.localdomain`.

I edited the hostname in `hive-site.xml` and restarted all the services, but still the same exception is coming. I could not find the place where cloudera is picking this hostname.

Could someone please let me know what would have went wrong.

Here is the exception

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost.localdomain
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
        ... 58 more
2014-07-04 07:16:06,354 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore: Shutting down hive metastore.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check your /etc/hosts file, it should have 
127.0.0.1 localhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

I changed the server_host value in `config.ini` file in `/etc/cloudera-scm-agent` to my host and after that when I restarted the services, all the services are running well